# No end event when piping inside "open"

Tags: node.js, stream

I am piping a download into a file, but wanting to make sure the file doesn't already exist. I've put the code up here for an easier exploration: https://tonicdev.com/tolmasky/streaming-piping-on-open-tester <-- this will show you the outputs (code also below inline).

So the thing is, it seems to work fine except for the done (end) event. The file ends up on the hard drive fine, each step is followed correctly (the structure is to ensure no "parallel" steps happen that aren't necessary -- if I do got.stream(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream({ flags: ... })), then the download will actually get kicked off even if the createWriteStream returns an error because the file is already there -- undesirable for the network).

The code is the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var got = require("got");

await download("https://www.apple.com", "./index.html");

function download(aURL, aDestinationFilePath)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        fs.createWriteStream(aDestinationFilePath, { flags: "wx" })
            .on("open", function()
            {
                const writeStream = this;

                console.log("SUCCESSFULLY OPENED!");

                got.stream(aURL)
                    .on("response", function(aResponse)
                    {
                        const contentLength = +aResponse.headers["content-length"] || 0;
                    console.log(aResponse.headers);
                        console.log("STARTING DOWNLOAD! " + contentLength);

                        this.on("data", () => console.log("certainly getting data"))

                        this.pipe(writeStream)                            
                            .on("error", reject)
                            .on("end", () => console.log("DONE!"))
                            .on("end", resolve);
                    })
            })
            .on("error", function(anError)
            {
                if (anError.code === "EEXIST") { console.log("oh");
                    resolve();}
                else
                    reject(anError);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't the event called `finish`?

Comment: I believe end is correct: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end . I'll give finish a try too though.

Comment: You seem to be correct, finish is indeed called. If you want to put the answer below I'll mark it correct. Thanks! Francisco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [stream docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), [readable.pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) returns the destination `Writable` stream, and the correct event emitted when a Writable is done would be [Event: 'finish'](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish).